# Problema ao carregar um feed de noticias aplicação android?

Tags: android, listview

Bom, estou tento problema com uma aplicação que mostra uma listagem de noticias, em alguns smartphones onde era pra aparecer a lista com as noticias a tela fica em branco, pesquisei na internet e encontrei que poderia ser conflito de dns e seria resolvido alterando algumas informações no roteador, existe outra forma de resolver este problema alterando algo no código do aplicativo android? (testei em outros dispositivos e o aplicativo funcionou)

Comment: Se você não mostrar o código que você está usando para carregar o feed, ninguém vai poder te ajudar. Leia: [como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Muito Obrigado, mas acredito que o problema não seja ao  carregar o feed, mas sim algo com os dispositivos que não pegam... Mas vou revisar o código que eu uso, pra carregar as noticias.

Comment: Ah, certo. Tudo bem. Eu acredito que o problema possa ser mais no dispositivo e não no seu app. Talvez seja até mesmo um problema de conexão. Sugiro testar dois dispositivo (um que não pega e outro que pega) na mesma conexão para ver se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Sim, obrigado, farei isso, talvez seja o problema com a conexão.